# Changes in GPT2/GPT3 model during few shot learning

Tags: nlp, gpt-2, gpt-3

During transfer learning, we take a pre-trained network and some observation pair (input and label), and use these data to fine-tune the weight by use of backpropagation. However, during one shot/few shot learning, according to this paper- 'Language Models are Few-Shot Learners' (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14165.pdf), "No gradient updates are performed". Then what changes happen to the models like GPT2 and GPT3 during one shot/few shot learning?

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing could be improved. "Few-shot learning" is a technique that involves training a model on a small amount of data, rather than a large dataset. This type of learning does not require gradient updates, which are typically used in traditional machine learning algorithms. GPT-x is capable of generating human-like text by predicting the next word or sequence of words based on the context provided. However, its main function is to complete text based on an input prompt, rather than to learn from scratch.

To use GPT-3 effectively, you can create an input prompt that includes a clear context and any relevant information. For example:

> Human: Hello Friendly AI.
> Friendly AI: Hello, I'm ready to help you.
> Human: $user_prompt

Then, you can paste the prompt from the user in $user_prompt and let GPT-3 generate a full response based on the context and its understanding of language.

Answer (score 1):

**Then what changes happen to the models like GPT2 and GPT3 during one shot/few shot learning?**

There is no change to the model at all. The model does not learn anything preservably. What they do is give the "training examples" as context to the model and the model generates an output at the end of this context. Figure 2.1 *(Brown, Tom B., et al. "Language models are few-shot learners."(2020).)* shows examples of  input for the fine-tuning, zero-shot-learning and few-shot-learning.

As you see, the training examples are part of the input and must be given each time a prediction shall be done. Therefore no change happened to the model.
[image: Brown, Tom B., et al. "Language models are few-shot learners."(2020), Figure 2.1]Brown, Tom B., et al. "Language models are few-shot learners."(2020)

Answer (score 0):

You may think that there are some changes because the model returns better results in the case of a few-shot training. However, it is the same model but having a different context as an input. GPT-2 and GPT-3 both are auto-regressive models meaning that the output also depends on the context.
More examples would mean a more clear context and, thus, the chance to obtain the desired results increases.